# retriving longurl from json data in php

Tags: php, json

i have a json data:

```
{ "success": true, "payment_request": { "id": "3e64d6cbe5ab4829a34845ba69e6f1bb", "phone": "+918562074512", "email": "abcd1@gmail.com", "buyer_name": "just a name", "amount": "10.00", "purpose": "Demo PAID Package", "expires_at": null, "status": "Pending", "send_sms": false, "send_email": true, "sms_status": null, "email_status": "Pending", "shorturl": null, "longurl": "https://test.instamojo.com/@justaname/3e64d6cbe5ab4829a34845ba69e6f1bb", "redirect_url": "http://www.mywebsite.in/exam/Checkouts/Instamojopostpayment/", "webhook": "http://www.example.com/webhook/", "allow_repeated_payments": false, "customer_id": null, "created_at": "2018-05-09T15:05:03.712593Z", "modified_at": "2018-05-09T15:05:03.712614Z" } }
```

now i need to fetch **longurl**  from it in php variable.

i am trying everything mentioned [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)..but no idea what wrong i am doing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The JSON is fine and valid. What issue or error are you experiencing with accessing `longurl`? Add some of your code to your question.

Comment: you have the URL in json,right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try like this with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$array = json_decode($string,1); //decoding it as an array with 2nd argument 1
echo $array['payment_request']['longurl'];
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1001721

Comment: Thanks @Being Sunny it worked for me, i was using json_decode($string)...

one more thing if you can help me :
i am getting return url as : http://www.example.in/exam/Checkouts/Instamojopostpayment/?payment_id=MOJO8510005A25097044&payment_request_id=f3bb93e08d344400b182259963924f69

now here Instamojopostpayment supposed to be a function, in which i should pass paymenmt_id and payment_request_id..

Could you help me to do that as well??

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '{ "success": true, "payment_request": { "id": "3e64d6cbe5ab4829a34845ba69e6f1bb", "phone": "+918562074512", "email": "abcd1@gmail.com", "buyer_name": "just a name", "amount": "10.00", "purpose": "Demo PAID Package", "expires_at": null, "status": "Pending", "send_sms": false, "send_email": true, "sms_status": null, "email_status": "Pending", "shorturl": null, "longurl": "https://test.instamojo.com/@justaname/3e64d6cbe5ab4829a34845ba69e6f1bb", "redirect_url": "http://www.mywebsite.in/exam/Checkouts/Instamojopostpayment/", "webhook": "http://www.example.com/webhook/", "allow_repeated_payments": false, "customer_id": null, "created_at": "2018-05-09T15:05:03.712593Z", "modified_at": "2018-05-09T15:05:03.712614Z" } }';
$json = json_decode($string);

echo $json->payment_request->longurl; // echo https://test.instamojo.com/@justaname/3e64d6cbe5ab4829a34845ba69e6f1bb
```

Answer (score 0):

payment_request->longurl;            // object format

$l = json_decode($k, true); 
echo $l['payment_request']['longurl'];          // array

//echo phpinfo();

?>